# java @Schedule stopped working after system time changed back for two hours

Tags: java, time, cron, ntp

I have an java app with a cron job marked with @Schedule, the java version is

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I run the app on jboss7.1

We have changed the system time of the machine two hours back basically there was no ntp installed and we installed it to correct the time, because it was out of date.

After that the cron job stoped working. Even if I restart jboss it doesn't help.

There are also no errors in the log that could indicate that something went wrong. Also none of the System.out I've putted in the code is not written to output so I suppose that the code is not executed at all.

My cron job:

```
@Singleton
@Lock(LockType.READ)
public class InstanceUpdater {

@EJB
FourPmInstanceBL fourPmInstanceBL;
@EJB
VMWareHandler vmWareHandler;
@EJB
PuppetHandler puppetHandler;
@EJB
FourPmInstanceHandler fourPmInstanceHandler;
@Inject
private Event<InstanceStatusChangeEvent> instanceStatusChangeEvent;

@Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*/10")
public void startTimer() {
    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> Instance updater started " + new Date());

    for (FourPmInstance instance : fourPmInstanceBL.getInstanceToProcess()) {

        Date currentTime = new Date();
        boolean canAcceptInstance = true;
        //neaded 30 sec delay betwen acceptance because of vmware cocnurent template reading problem.
        if(instance.getProcessAt() != null){
            canAcceptInstance = currentTime.after(instance.getProcessAt());
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> Instance can be accepted: " + canAcceptInstance);
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> Proces instance at " + instance.getProcessAt());
        }

        //Long instancesInProgres = fourPmInstanceBL.getCountinProgres();

        if (instance.getStatus().equals(InstanceStatus.NEW)) {

            if(canAcceptInstance){
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> Instance accepted " + instance.getName());
                try {
                    instanceStatusChangeEvent.fire(new InstanceStatusChangeEvent(instance,InstanceStatus.IN_PROGRESS));
                    fourPmInstanceHandler.registerNewInstance(instance);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    instanceStatusChangeEvent.fire(new InstanceStatusChangeEvent(instance,InstanceStatus.ERROR));
                }
            }

        } else {

            try {
                instanceStatusChangeEvent.fire(new InstanceStatusChangeEvent(instance,InstanceStatus.IN_PROGRESS));
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>> Instance update " + instance.getName());
                fourPmInstanceHandler.updateHardwareAndLicence(instance);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                instanceStatusChangeEvent.fire(new InstanceStatusChangeEvent(instance,InstanceStatus.ERROR));
            } 


        }


    }



}    

}
```

Comment: When you say it is not working, what do you mean? Is there an exception or does the job simply not execute?

Comment: There are no errors in the log, so I suppose the job does not execute, I will update the question.